# SQL Interjection Error

Tags: c#, sqlite

What I had tried 
I had tried using data adapter but it didn't work I tried using data reader but I am not sure on how to go about using it properly.

I want to get the value 12.0 to be saved and displayed into data grid view at the moment if I key 12.1 it also works only like 12.0 it will be entered and displayed as 12 at the data grid view

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBoxstaff.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select gaugeman");  // not to let thecombobox empty
        return;
    }
    else if (comboBoxcompondrubber.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select Compond Rubber");// not to let thecombobox empty
        return;

    }
    else if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Key in W.S thickness");// not to let thetextbox empty
        return;

    }
    else if (textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Key in G.S thickness");// not to let thecombobox empty

    }
    SQLiteConnection insertsess = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\test1db");
    string insert12 = "INSERT INTO thickness (GaugeMan,Dateandtime, CompondRubber,GSthickness,WSthicknes) VALUES ('" + comboBoxstaff.Text + "','" + label2.Text + "', '" + comboBoxcompondrubber.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox1.Text + "')";   //insert statment
    SQLiteCommand ins1 = new SQLiteCommand(insert12, insertsess);
    insertsess.Open();
    ins1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Data had been saved");// showed when the message is being saved

    SQLiteConnection sesscheck = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\test1db");
    SQLiteCommand chk1;
    chk1 = sesscheck.CreateCommand();
    chk1.CommandText = "SELECT GaugeMan,Dateandtime, CompondRubber,GSthickness,WSthicknes FROM thickness WHERE CompondRubber = '" + comboBoxcompondrubber.Text.Trim() + "'";
   sesscheck.Open();
    DataTable thicknessTable = new DataTable();
    //DataTable thicknessTable = new DataTable();
    SQLiteDataReader reader = chk1.ExecuteReader();
    thicknessTable.Load(reader);
    //SQLiteDataReader reader1 = chk2.ExecuteReader();
    //thicknessTable.Load(reader1);
    sesscheck.Close();

    dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

}
```

Comment: This is a presentation problem, I think.  You should just be using something in Java like a decimal formatter to use one decimal place.  Then, `12` would come out as `12.0`.

Comment: any example for me to see?

Comment: But on my SQLite is does show 12.0

Comment: Hmm...my point is not getting across to you at all.  Ignore, completely, whatever you see on SQLite, because it too is showing presentation.  Just check the value coming back to your C# code, and _format_ it the way you want to see it.